# Calculation the negative inverse of values <1 in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, inverse

I am a beginner using R so apologies if this is a stupid question.
I have a data frame that has a column containing 7000 values. I want to calculate the negative inverse (-1/value) for all values <1 in that column while leaving all values >= 1 unchanged.

What is the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try `replace` like below

```
replace(v, v<1,-1/v[v<1])
```

or a more mathy way

```
(1 - 2 * (v < 1)) * v^(1 - 2 * (v < 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

say your data is called `df` and has a column called `values` you could do:

```
ifelse(df$values < 1, 
       -1 / df$values, #negative inverse of all <1 
       df$values) #keep others the same
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also also subset and replace your vector where your condition is `TRUE`:

```
v[v < 1] <- -1 / v[v < 1]
```